# Symfony 2.7, Stream a file with StreamedResponse, requests for information

Tags: php, html, apache, symfony

I'm working on a symfony app with videos. And i need to stream those videos and then display in an html5 player.
I used this blog post : http://ailoo.net/2013/03/stream-a-file-with-streamedresponse-in-symfony/ and i think it's working fine.

```
$response = new StreamedResponse(
        function () use ($file) {
                    readfile($file);
                }, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'video/' . $formatVideo)

            );
return $this->render('SQMovieBundle:Movie:displayMovie.html.twig', array('test' => $response));
```

But it's the first time i work with things like buffer, i read i have some configuation to do with apache (i'm using mamp on mac os).
And i have no idea for display my video in twig.

Feel free to give me indications.

Comment: Does it pass a video or an URL to the video to Twig?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: it pass an object StreamedReponse, {{ dump(test) }} gives me :
StreamedResponse {#1126 ▼
  #callback: Closure {#1128 ▶}
  #streamed: false
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#1157 ▶}
  #content: null
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}

Comment: @malcolm i know how to use the html 5 player but i need to know how to access to my file from this object reponse or the buffer idk in order to fulfill the src="".

Comment: Is it not should be like `src="path/to/controller/with/streamed/response"` ?

Comment: the issue is I don't know how to access to the file path from reponse.

Comment: @stax you need to make two response, one to stream data e other to twig view.

Answer (score 0):

There's much cleaner way of streaming a file in Symfony, simply return an instance of the [BinaryFileResponse](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/BinaryFileResponse.php) class:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($pathToTheFile);
```